# c++ appending text into a string until see a specific character

Tags: c++, string

I have more than one input files like this:

```
>1aab_
GKGDPKKPRGKMSSYAFFVQTSREEHKKKHPDASVNFSEFSKKCSERWKT
MSAKEKGKFEDMAKADKARYEREMKTYIPPKGE
>1j46_A
MQDRVKRPMNAFIVWSRDQRRKMALENPRMRNSEISKQLGYQWKMLTEAE
KWPFFQEAQKLQAMHREKYPNYKYRPRRKAKMLPK
>1k99_A
MKKLKKHPDFPKKPLTPYFRFFMEKRAKYAKLHPEMSNLDLTKILSKKYK
ELPEKKKMKYIQDFQREKQEFERNLARFREDHPDLIQNAKK
>2lef_A
MHIKKPLNAFMLYMKEMRANVVAESTLKESAAINQILGRRWHALSREEQA
KYYELARKERQLHMQLYPGWSARDNYGKKKKRKREK
```

Here, what I have to do:

```
vector <string> names;
vector <string> seqs;
names.resize(total); //"total" is already known.
seqs.resize(total);
counter=0;char input;
while ((input = myInput.get()) != EOF)
{
   if(input=='>')
      names[counter]= take all line (>1aab_, >1j46_A, so...)
   else
      untill the see next '>' append the character into sequence[counter]
   counter++;
}
```

Finally it will be like this:

```
names[0]=">1aab_"
sequence[0]="GKGDPKKPRGKMSSYAFFVQTSREEHKKKHPDASVNFSEFSKKCSERWKTMSAKEKGKFEDMAKADKARYEREMKTYIPPKGE"
```

and so on..

I am thinking about for 2 hours and I couldn't figure out it. Can anyone help about that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RSahu Which part you didn't understand? I just need the `if-else` block in the loop.

Comment: Without looking at actual code, it is hard telling where the problem is.

Comment: @WhoCares What did you already try yourself? We're not achieve _Gimme teh codez plz_ questions well here.

Comment: I just can't find two string commands. Thats all. And I don't want u guys to code me, I need ideas, pseudocode maybe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to solve it; I'll present some examples but I'm not testing/compiling this code, so there may be minor bugs - the logic is the important bit.

Since your pseudocode appears to be processing the input character by character, I've taken that as a requirement.

---

The way you seem to be thinking about it would be implemented with essentially a pair of loops - one for reading the name, the other for reading the sequence - which are enclosed in an outer loop, in order to process all records.

This would look something like the following:

```
// first character in file should be a '>', indicating the start
// of a record.
input = myInput.get();
if (input != '>')
{
  std::cerr << "Malformed input file!" << std::endl;
  return /*...*/;
}

do
{
   // record name continues up until the newline
   while ((input = myInput.get()) != EOF)
   {
     if (input == '\n' || input == '\r')
       break;
     names[counter].push_back(input);
   }

   // read sequence until we hit a '>' or EOF
   while ((input = myInput.get()) != EOF)
   {
     if (input == '>')
     {
       // advance to next record number
       counter++;
       break;
     }
     sequence[counter].push_back(input);
   }
} while (input != EOF && counter < total);
```

You'll also notice I moved the check for the initial '>' to before the loop, just as a way of ingesting (and discarding) the character, as well as a basic sanity check of the input. This is because we really use this character to mark the *end of the sequence* (rather than the "start of a record") - when we enter the loop, we assume we're already reading the record name.

---

Another way to approach it is to use a state machine. Essentially, this utilises additional variables to track the *state* the parser is in.

For this particular case, you only have two states: either you're reading a record name, or the sequence. So, we can just use a single boolean to track which state we're in.

Armed with the state variable, we can then make decisions about what to do with the character we just read based upon the state we're in. At the simplest level here, if we're in "read the record name" state, we add the character to the `names` variable, otherwise we add it to the `sequence` variable.

```
// state flag to indicate if we're currently reading a name line,
// i.e. a line starting with ">"
// This should be set true by the first record we encounter, so
// we'll set it false (to indicate we're reading a sequence) in
// order to allow us to detect bad input files.
bool reading_name = false;

// indicate we're on the first record, so we can avoid incrementing
// the record counter
bool first_record = true;

// process input character-by-character until end of file
while ((input = myInput.get()) != EOF)
{
   // check for start of new record
   if (input == '>')
   {
     // for robustness, verify we're not already reading a name,
     // as this probably indicates invalid input
     if (reading_name)
     {
       std::cerr << "Input is malformed?!" << endl;
       break;
     }

     // switch to reading name state
     reading_name = true;

     // advance to next record, but only if it isn't the first record
     if (first_record)
     {
       // disable the first_record flag, and explicitly set the
       // record counter to 0.
       first_record = false;
       counter = 0;
     }
     else if (++counter >= total)
     {
       std::cerr << "Error: too many records!" << std::endl;
       break;
     }
   }
   // first character in file should start a new record
   else if (first_record)
   {
     std::cerr << "Missing record start character at beginning of input!" << std::endl;
     break;
   }
   // make sure we are processing a valid record number
   else if (counter >= total)
   {
     std::cerr << "Invalid record number!" << std::endl;
     break;
   }
   // continue reading the name
   else if (reading_name)
   {
      // check if we've reached the end of the line; you
      // may also want/need to check for \r if your input
      // files may have Windows-style line endings
      if (input == '\n')
      {
        // switch to reading sequence state
        reading_name = false;
      }
      else
      {
        // add character to current name
        names[counter].push_back(input);
      }
   }
   // continue reading the sequence
   else
   {
      // you might need to handle line ending characters here,
      // maybe just skipping them?

      // add character to current sequence
      sequence[counter].push_back(input);
   }
}
```

This adds a fair amount of complexity, which is of questionable value for this particular exercise, but does make adding additional states easier in future. It also has the benefit of only a single place in the code where I/O is done, which reduces the chances of errors (not checking for EOF, overflow array bounds, etc.).

In this case, we're actually using the '>' character as an indicator that a new record is starting, so we add a bit of extra logic to make sure that all works properly with the record counter. You could also just use a signed integer for your `counter` variable and start it at `-1`, so it will increment to 0 at the start of the first record, but using signed variables to index into arrays isn't a good idea.

---

There are more ways to approach this problem, but hopefully this gives you somewhere to start on your own solution.